# Force jQuery to match div with both class tags, not just one

Tags: jquery, class, selector

If I have this html

```
<ul class="link color">...</ul>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(".link li").click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

or

```
$(".color li").click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

it works fine.

But I only want to trigger when the class has BOTH link and color. How can I tell jQuery to only trigger on both existing as this doesn't work:

```
$(".link .color li").click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".link.color li").click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

The reason why `$(".link .color li")` doesn't select it is because it is trying to grab all li that are children of the class color that are the children of class link. When you put the spaces in there it ends up working it's way down the DOM, but when you put the selectors right next to each other it only grabs the ones that meet all of the selectors.

Comment: BAH! how effing simple! the stupid space was the only thing.. THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is coming from the space you put between 2 classnames in your seletor.
Just put them close together without any space.

By writing this way :

```
$(".link .color li")
```

You will get the **children** with classname "color" of the parent tag with class "link".
But to write it like this:

```
$(".link.color li")
```

You can get the tag with both class "color" and "link"

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".color li, .link li").something.... //has one or the other
$(".color.link li").something.... //has both
```